# ImageButton in Updatepanel fires only on first Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, updatepanel

I have the following Updatepanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPopUps" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="panelOverlay" runat="server" class="Overlay" Visible="false">
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="panelPopUpPanel" runat="server" class="PopUpPanel" Visible="false"
            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="5px" Height="250px">
            <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border-bottom: solid 2; border-top: solid 2;
                border-left: solid 2; border-right: solid 2;">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 100%; padding-left: 10px;" colspan="2">
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PopupHeader" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <asp:ImageButton id="cmdClosePopUp" runat="server" src="../Navigation/PopupImages/Close.png" alt="Close Popup"
                            OnClick="ClosePopup"  align="right" />
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border_top">
                    <td colspan="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 80%">
                    <td align="center">
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PopupMessage" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 10%">
                    <td colspan="3" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                        <input type="hidden" id="StartDivID" value="0" runat="server" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="NewsCount" value="" runat="server" />
                        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="btn_ok" src="../Navigation/PopupImages/Ok_Button.jpg" alt="Close Popup"
                              OnClick="ClosePopup" align="right" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My problem is that if i click on one of these two Buttons after PageLoad it works fine.

Through  `$(document).ready(function()` i refresh the Page every 60 seconds. The PopUp pops up, but the Buttons do not fire anymore.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

                setInterval("RefreshGrid()", 60000);

        });


        function RefreshGrid() {
            var WebGrid1 = ISGetObject("WebGrid1");
            WebGrid1.Refresh();
        }
```

Do someone has an idea, where could be the problem? Why is it only working on the first pageload?

Comment: What exactly are you doing in `$(document).ready(function() { })`?

Comment: Have you tried rebinding the events after the refresh? `$('#btn_ok').click(...`

Comment: Where do i have to do this? in the ready function? Can you give me an example? Thank you

Comment: Just put it right bellow the `WebGrid1.Refresh();` call :)

Comment: i tried it now, but still not working :(. Is it possible to rebind or Register the Buttons on PageLoad on Server Side?

Comment: Yes... perhaps, maybe. I did some researching, try my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a reserved function called `pageLoad` that runs at every postback. Bind your events inside it.

```
function pageLoad() {
    $('#btn_ok, #cmdClosePopUp').click(ClosePopup); //Something like this.
}
```

It feels like you're losing the link to the handlers when you refresh. This should fix that.

Comment: Another solution is to use a asp:Linkbutton with an image or a normal asp:button. With that Buttons the Codebehind fires everytime without rebinding the events. I have no idea why the ImageButton is not working.